# How to Change Bigcommerce Blog's Thumbnail Image Size

Tags: blogs, bigcommerce

I want to `change blog's thumbnail image size` to full size in bigcommerce on blog page.
I have checked in bigcommerce admin panel, but unable to find such kind of settings.

Please help. Any help will really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is something best to contact technical support on as it focused on the control panel. There isn't a way, FWIW.

Comment: Really ?? Ok. then let me contact to bigcommerce technical support, apart from that any other answers will be really appreciated. Thanks